# count specific value on column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, parsing, sql-like

I have table trx

```
id    name     respond
1     john     DETIL!518050381482|202003|SRI RAHAYU               |  R1|450|6784|6866|0|0|0|0|047421CB6333E1FB10624B8BD3462256|2020-03-31 20:19:12|37881|2750|0|0|ASLI:asialink|LISTRIK|"Informasi Hubungi Call Center 123 Atau Hub PLN Terdekat :"                     . Powered by Bukopinet.|123            |21d94ad2fb7127e7ccbc5928c22996f1*!93116677|93116677|79
2     dana     DETIL!518030384979|202003|MUSJARI                  |  R1|900|450|15769|0|0|0|0|047421CB6333E546FEB23EA60FE279C5|2020-03-31 20:53:28|462570|2750|0|0|ASLI:asialink|LISTRIK|"Informasi Hubungi Call Center 123 Atau Hub PLN Terdekat :"                     . Powered by Bukopinet.|123            |700ab80876c7d0f0e3ea5621c29988e3*!89065543|89065543|79
3     toni     DETIL!518030384770|202003|KASBUN                   |  R1|450|15502|15603|0|0|0|0|047421CB6333E552C7AC8A082139A502|2020-03-31 20:54:17|48227|2750|0|0|ASLI:asialink|LISTRIK|"Informasi Hubungi Call Center 123 Atau Hub PLN Terdekat :"                     . Powered by Bukopinet.|123            |ec47a682782daa193cd3b9e8a241664e*!88781316|88781316|79
```

I want to count how many 450 value(after R1) on column respond.

I used `select count(*) from trx where respond like '%|450|%'`

but it showed 3 because id 2 has value |450| but I only expect value after R1

it should be 2

Comment: Once you get into `something seperated lists` in a single cell it is often better to do this in the program rather than in raw sql. Shows why doing this is such a bad idea though. Think how difficult it would be if you wanted the `R1` and `0` in section 7?? :)

Comment: Well, this is one way to learn normal form 1.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
where respond like '%R1|450|%'
```

This would work for your sample data.

You can be a bit more flexible with regular expressions:

```
where respond regex 'R1[^|]*\\|450\\|'
```

This phrases as: `'R1'` followed by 0 to n characters other than `'|'`, followed by `'|450|'`.

Comment: this is not work because in real data, R1 could be R1M, TAM, etc.